# Inventory optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming

I have n products. $(y_1, y_2, ...y_n)$ is my inventory vector. This should last for a certain period.

Assume $m$ transactions will be made in this period.

Each transaction will have only one of these $n$ items (they are substitutional products). The probabilities of purchase of each product are known, $p_1,p_2,p_3,...,p_n.$ They add up to 1.

Revenue given by each product is known $r_1,r_2,...r_n$.

OBJECTIVE

Maximize :- $R_m(y_1, y_2, ...,y_n)$
which is the revenue made in this period, given $m$ purchases are made and given an inventory vector.

Decision variable is obviously the inventory vector.

CONSTRAINT

$y_1+y_2+...+y_n \leq C$  [capacity constraint]

How do you approach this problem? It's more tricky than your usual lp problem which is what I'm familiar with. I have done a bit of searching but didn't across similar problems.

Expected revenue for one transaction is just sumproduct of probablities and profits. So we have $m$ transactions and just multiplying by $m$ is wrong since we don't know if the products still remain in inventory by the time we reach $m-th$ transaction (quantity is what we have to decide).

Comment: what are you asking? what are your own thoughts about how to approach this problem?

Comment: Oh i guess I should have written a bit more.. I'll edit

Comment: Do you mean that if before the initial inventory is $(y_1,y_2,...,y_i,...,y_n)$, it will be $(y_1,y_2,...,y_i-1,...,y_n)$ after the first transaction, or can it be $(y_1,y_2,...,y_i-k,...,y_n)$ and $k$ is also a random variable?

Comment: No just one would be sold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in each transaction only one unit is sold, I guess your objective function is something like

$$ \sum_j^m \sum_i^n r_i.p_i·1_{ij},$$

where $1_{ij}$ is an indicator function, that takes value $1$ if after $j$ transactions there is still inventory left for product $i$ and $0$ otherwise. If initially you have $y_i$ units of this particular product, after $j$ transactions you can expect to have $y_i-j·p_i$ units left (because the number of units sold has a binomial distribution). Therefore   $1_{ij}=1_{y_i-j·p_i>0},$ the indicator function will take value $1$ if $1y_i-j·p_i>0,$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I've understood it.

Comment: The indicator function's boolean expression would have (j-1) though not j right?

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: Can this function's maxima be actually found using a solver? I used scipy's minimze function in python and it failed. It doesn't seem like a convex function so it can't be done?